# How to turn off / let float a servo attached to GPIO

Tags: gpio, pwm, servo, pigpio

I'm driving servos attached to GPIO, powered from external PSU and using PIGPIO Library through node.js - everything works just fine but I don't know how to completely "shut down" the servos - once they're set to a position they will try to maintain that position resisting external force - I get this is how servos work but how can I make them "relax" / shut down completely? Preferably with an only-software solution / not using a relay to cut the power physically?

Answer (score 1):

The normal way is just to stop the servo pulses.  You do that with pigpio by specifying a pulse width of 0.

Remember that when the servo isn't getting pulses the only thing which will keep it in place is the friction in its gearing.